# Simple C program and understanding the output

Tags: c

I gonna have exam from C next week. I will have to type, what is the output of given C programs. We also get some examples of those programs, to know what to prepare for. Unfortunately i don't have too much time to dive deep in C now so what i'm trying to do is just get some general knowledge.

So i have the given program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int A[] = {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19};
#define MaxJ (sizeof A / sizeof A[0]-1)

int tot(int j)
{
    if (2*j <= MaxJ)
        return tot(2*j) + tot(2*j+1);
    else if (j<=MaxJ)
        return A[j];
    else return 0;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d", tot(1));
    return 0;
}
```

The question is, what exactly happens in that 'if' statement? I understand that MaxJ is 8 and why, but the output 60 confuses me. From what i thought is that we passes value 1 as an argument to tot(), then multiplaying that 1 by 2 till we get 16 which is > MaxJ so we go to else if and return A[j], which should be 19 for j = 8. But that's not correct.

Comment: "*then multiplaying that 1 by 2 till we get 16*". That implies a loop. But an `if` is not a loop. So how does the "till we get" happen in your understanding? This is a recursive function (ie calls itself) and those can admittedly be difficult to understand at first. What you have described is only the last call in one of the call tree branches. That result needs to be fed back up the call tree all the way up to the initial call. The best thing to do is to write it out line by line on a piece of paper. You need to recursively calculate the result of `tot` and lay out the full call tree.

Comment: Thanks for Your effort. I followed up your instruction and write it down on a piece of paper, now i can see from where that 60 came from. I went through the branches and see that individual "returns" from branches are a[8]=19, 0, a[5]=11, a[6]=13, a[7]=17. I still don't get why those values can be added tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add some debug `printf`s you can see what is going on:

```
int A[] = {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28};
#define MaxJ (sizeof A / sizeof A[0]-1)

int tot(int j)
{
    if (2*j <= MaxJ)
    {
        printf(" >>>> j = %d 2*j = %d\n", j, 2*j);
        return tot(2*j) + tot(2*j+1);
    }
    else 
    if (j<=MaxJ)
    {
        printf("j = %d A[j] = %d\n", j, A[j]);
        return A[j];
    }
    else return 0;
}
int main()
{
    printf("MAXJ = %zu\n", MaxJ);
    printf("%d", tot(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Analyzing it you will discover that the function is returning the sum of the upper half array elements (if number of elements is odd then that half is larger by one than the lower half)